# Formula for matching multiple row cell including blank cell

Tags: vba, excel, formulas

Well, my question is, What is the formula for matching multiple row cell, if Match TRUE else FALSE then show the different row cell value in next column also sheet have blanks cell too so formula avoid blank cell and result is TRUE.

Please follow the sheet

[image]

I am using this formula:

```
{=AND(EXACT(A2:M2,A2))}
```

and this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:M2,A2)=13,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

But it match with blank cell, I need formula to only for existed matching row cell value then result is TRUE and FALSE. and if False then show that row cell column value in next column

Thanks
BN

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, I tested this and it works: `=IF(COUNTIF(A2:M2,A2)+COUNTIF(B2:M2,"")=13,TRUE,FALSE)`. It counts the number of times the row header appears and then counts the blanks, and if the sum of the two equal 13, you know its an exact match, taking blanks into consideration.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHoltzman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three standard formulas use in M2:O2 in the following image are,

```
=COUNTIF(A2:L2, A2)=COUNTA(A2:L2)
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:L2, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:L)/((A2:L2<>A2)*SIGN(LEN(A2:L2))), 1)), "")
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:L$1, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:L)/((A2:L2<>A2)*SIGN(LEN(A2:L2))), 1)), "")
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: ROGUE_ENTRIES]

The conditional formatting rule for B2:L9 was based upon the following formula,

```
=AND(LEN(B2), B2<>$A2)
```

Comment: Well done @jeeped,, Also I have another question in the above work sheet through this formulas I can get results....but there is another stuff which is in the row cell there are multiple different values then what is formula for ROGUE AND HDR...Thanks BN

Comment: I'm afraid that I do not really understand your new criteria. However, it does sound like [Another Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625). It is probably best to [close off](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this inquiry and initiate a [New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). That will give you the opportunity to properly supply the new information.